# Using function variable in a object attribute

Tags: php, oop, function, variables

So I got this code:

```
class DAO
{
    private $_connect = "oci_connect";

    function Conect()
    {
        $connect = $this->$_connect;
        $connect($user, $pass, $conStr);
    }
}
```

It works well. PHP recognizes the function stored in the object attribute, but there's a way to simplify like this:

```
class DAO
{
    private $_connect = "oci_connect";

    function Conect()
    {
        $this->_connect($user, $pass, $conStr);
    }
}
```

I want to use the object attribute instead to stock it on another variable to use it as a function. In this case PHP think that is an object method and not a variable. It's possible to do it in other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
call_user_func_array(array($this, $this->_connect), array($user, $pass, $conStr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following php function : [call_user_func()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) it should do what you expect.

Comment: Great suggestion but call_user_func_array worked like a charm